# How to know if an Activity has been created and access its data?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I have my broadcast receiver which receives sms and creates notifications.
My app needs a login and I don't know how to procede.

Should I launch the login activity if the app has been destroyed?
or should I access saved shared preferences if any?

My ideal solution is to launch login activity if the app has been closed and resuming an activity if it's still in the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check inside the `OnResume()` method of your Activity/Service if it's connected to the server. If it is not display the login activity (or use stored, encrypted credentials) and reconnect.

Comment: the activity can be used offline too, you just need to log in first

Comment: Okay, so please specify your question, provide some code... Right now I don't know what exactly you're asking.